# Castle Windsor dependency injection: Use the caller type as a parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, log4net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

The following class is registered in the Windsor Castle container:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public Foo(ILog log)
        {
             _log = log;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

`ILog` is a log4net logger, currently registered like this:

```
Component.For<ILog>().UseFactoryMethod(
    () => LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName));
```

I would like to create a logger named like the **calling type** (in this case `"MyNamespace.Foo"`)  rather than like the calling assembly. Is there a way to do it, except for using reflection to play with stack frames?

Comment: have you looked at the logging facility in castle?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13388644/25702 for possible answer to this

Answer (score 3):

The castle windsor logging facility does what you want. It has integration with log4net or NLog already (see: [how to set up logging facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245354/where-how-castle-windsor-sets-up-logging-facility)).

If you are curious still, you can examine the source code to see how exactly it can be done. Take a look at the [log4net Integration source](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core/tree/master/src/Castle.Services.Logging.log4netIntegration) and the [logging facility](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Windsor/tree/master/src/Castle.Facilities.Logging) source and especially at the LoggerResolver class (which does the name resolving).